# Encrypt control channel only (not data channel) with FtpWebRequest C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftps

I want to know whether there is a way to use `FtpWebRequest` class in C# to establish secure command channel between client and server (encrypt only commands, but not data channel). When I set the `EnableSsl` to true the `FtpWebRequest` class use secure data channel (encrypt commands and data channel) and send `PROT` and `PBSZ` commands, but I want avoid it. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Then it make no sense to encrypt only one part. You must write your own ftpWebRequest for that.

Answer (score 0):

The `FtpWebRequest` does not support control-connection-only encryption.

When you set the `FtpWebRequest.EnableSsl`, these commands are send, no matter what:

```
AUTH TLS
PBSZ 0
PROT P
```

There's no way to make the `FtpWebRequest` send the `PROT` with other argument.

You have to use another FTP client implementation.